# Spring-XD deployment failure

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

Spring-XD running in a 3 container, 1 Admin, 1 Zk environment. My stream definition is as follows.

topic:test > processor | http-client > namedchannel

I get the following exception when i try to deploy the stream in one of the environment. It worked fine in other environment. Spring-XD version is 1.2.1

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter#0#0b0d7c9d-ba16-4f2c-9c9b-63e2284a42c0'; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [MessageChannelMonitor: [name=output, sends=0]] with key 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=output'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: 
,component=MessageChannel,name=output
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:770)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
```

Comment: How about to upgrade to the latest Spring XD version: http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/ ?

Comment: Is this a known issue in the older version of spring-xd? We are In production already with the same module and different stream definition . Trying to fix an issue by modifying the stream definition. Facing this issue while deploying modified stream definition. Upgrading the Spring-xd version is in our roadmap but its a longer route. Is there a workaround for this?